# Is that possible to make for each user table in database

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

i am working on program (WINDOWSFORM) that request for each user a datatable, thats mean every user have table with 8 columns and 23 rows.
my question is:
is that possible?
is the schema in the picture exact?
how can be the database schema?

in the second picture the type of view for each user
[image: dataschema]
[image: Exemple]
[image: gradebook]

Comment: It seems logic to create a single USER_DATA table with a UserID column

Comment: Why would you need a Table per User? All with the same Fields...

Comment: one to many is very much possible but all the tables look alike so I fail to see the reason for doing this... maybe you can feather explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: While possible it would be a weird and probably seriously flawed design.

Comment: i want that every time i open the program i can chois between users, for exemple gradebook and when i select that student it will open table with 8 columns and 23 rows populated with grades

Comment: @HaddadiAbdraouf what makes you think you can only do that with a table per user? You are mixing up storage and display concepts.

Comment: @insane_developer i am not sure of what i have made, i am looking for help to clarified and simplified the right method, if you look in the pictures (exemple) that what i want to do, so is that possible? is that correct?

Comment: @HaddadiAbdraouf there is nothing special about what you want. You have one User_Data table where you store all users' data, and to display an individual user's data all you need is a simple query that shows all columns where userId = theUserID, which will give you the 23 rows that were supposedly stored for that user.

Comment: Your design is bad because you would have to add a table i.e. change the database structure for each new user. Imagine having 10, 100, 1000 users! Ouch! - Instead all you (should) need to do is add new data.

Comment: If fields of each table are the same, you only need to design one table and add a new row each time a new user added.

Comment: @TaW can you give me n idea to better do that, i have 10 user i want each user have his own table like in the 3 picture

Comment: @XingyuZhao but each user have also 23 rows of data like in the 3 picture

Comment: _i want each user have his own table like in the 3 picture_ Well, as we all told yopu: __This is a bad idea.__ do what everybody tells you: Add a userID field zo the userdata table and you are good; all you need to do is include the ID in the queries.